# What is ethereum harmony for and what is a good starting point to get into Ethereum Dapp development?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, harmony

I think, I understand what Geth is for, and I think I understand that EthereumWallet uses Geth to do all the blockchain io.

I thought to understand that Mist is the wallet, but that seems aiming too low.

What is harmony for? Does it initialize a private Ethereum network?

Finally: Could you suggest a good starting point to get into Ethereum Dapp development?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is ethereum harmony for?

AFAIK, Ethereum Harmony provides a interface (includes a wallet and a command line interface) to interact with ethreum networks by running a node and it uses ethereumJ which is a Java implementation of ethereum protocol. It can be used to connect to main ethereum network, test networks or a private network.

> Could you suggest a good starting point to get into Ethereum Dapp
>   development?

In Dapp Development you need to learn two parts; smart contract development and the Dapp Interface development. As I feel it's always better to start with contract development.

For contract development, you need to first learn solidity and try out sample contracts.  Assuming you have a developer background and coding experiences, the [Solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/)  and the [greeter example](https://ethereum.org/greeter) provided from ethereum will give good start. And use [Remix IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org/) to test contracts with environment set as JavascriptVM. This will give you a good experience on solidity language and its behavior.

After that you may start to learn how to use web3 to connect with a ethereum network and start building  interface for dapps. You can learn by deploying test contracts to test nets or to a private net and trying to build interface for them. You may start studying about the Web3 JavaScript-API documentation [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API). [This Full Stack Hello World Voting Ethereum Dapp Tutorial](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2) might help you as well.

[Here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Dapp-Developer-Resources) are the dapp developer resources mentioned in the ethereum github wiki. Above process will help you to be familiar with these resources.

**NOTE :** I assume you have a sufficient idea about what is blockchain and ethereum. If not as the very first task you may learn the basics of blockchain concept and the ethereum implementation (contracts, accounts , mining etc.). If not you may start reading the [ethereum white paper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper) and [this ethereum development tutorial](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Development-Tutorial) before anything.

Comment: This would be a good answer but for the fact that the word harmony doesn't appear anywhere in.the text:)

Comment: Edit noted, voted

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer is in itself a good starting point! If I understand the harmony from your explanation, I can see it as a testing and analytics tool to see if my smart contracts behave properly when "in the wild", where wild also is a private or test network.

Comment: I am wondering and do not want to ask a new question on this @Achala Dissanayake. When I run Ethereum Harmony and start connection to Main server, will this download the ethereum blockchan data (over 300G now) on my machine? Or it only does with private server or perhaps it never does for any